# Push notification icon works on development but not in production

Tags: react-native, push-notification, icons, expo

I configured push notifications on a react-native application, all is working but the icon on the notification is only a black background on production.

I have the push notification icon with a of size 96x96, 8 bits and with transparency, is working in development with expo, showing the icon of the expo on the top left and on the right is showing my notification icon,

[image]

but when I do the release or I try it with `expo build:android` and install it on my phone it only shows an icon with black background.

[image]

Configuration of the app.json,

```
...
"notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/notification_icon.png"
},
...
```

Here is the icon:
[image]

The expected result is to show the push notification icon on production.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?